# Blank page when open url in new tab in Flutter Web (need to refresh)

Tags: javascript, flutter, flutter-web

I'm building an url, in Flutter web, and open it in new tab using JS. It opens fine, but don't load the url and return a blank page. I need to load/refresh the tab manually each time.

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;
js.context.callMethod('open', [_buildUrl(category, id)]);
```

```dart
String _buildUrl(String category, int id) {
    return "$_baseUrl/$category/$id"; 
}
```

Is it a normal behavior or did I miss something ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above approach is working fine on my end. Below is what I tried -

In the snippet, Method 1 is to trigger another page within the same website using Uri.base; and it is opening a new tab as expected.

```js
import 'dart:js' as js;
import 'dart:html' as html;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        // Method 1
        js.context.callMethod('open', [_buildUrl("Grocery", 101)]);
        // Method 2 - Alternative
        //html.window.open(_buildUrl("Grocery", 101), "new tab");
      },
      child: const Text('using JS method'),
    ),
  );
}

String _buildUrl(String category, int id) {
  return "${Uri.base}$category/$id";
}
```

Alternatively, if its still troublesome, you can try using the **window.open()** method from html library in Flutter. I have mentioned it as Method 2 in above code snippet. That will also open a new tab in the same browser.

Comment: It works fine using the second method with html ! Thanks a lot